# How to find the UV vertex count? is there a script to do so?

Tags: scripting, uv

While unwrapping for Unity 3D game development "UV vertex" count is an important aspect.

I was reading this [GPU: Optimizing Model Geometry](https://docs.unity3d.com/355/Documentation/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html)
It says "Try to keep the number of UV mapping seams and hard edges (doubled-up vertices) as low as possible"

ie. Every time i create a seam or split UV i double that many nulber of UV vertices. If so ...

**How do i find out what is the total and individual object UV vertex count in Blender ?**

**Is there a script to find UV vertex count?**

Comment: What do you mean by "UV count"? I've done extensive work in Unity for several years and I've never heard of a "UV count"

Comment: @ Keith M, sorry i was not very clear in my question i feel. If you go by this link "GPU: Optimizing Model Geometry" https://docs.unity3d.com/355/Documentation/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html     
Try to keep the number of UV mapping seams and hard edges (doubled-up vertices) as low as possible
Do they mean UV vertex count? if so how to find it out?

Comment: Working for 15 years with games his is pretty trivial stuff. You don't optimize the UV vert count, you make UVs according to your texturing needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little rushed, and I still need to test it a little bit more, but it seems to return the correct number of UV vertices for simple meshes. UV unwrap your mesh and run this script in object mode:

```
import bpy
from collections import defaultdict

mesh=bpy.context.active_object.data

uv_layer = mesh.uv_layers[0].data
verts=defaultdict(list)
loc=defaultdict(list)
count=0

for p in mesh.polygons:
    for l in p.loop_indices:
        index = mesh.loops[l].vertex_index
        uv = uv_layer[l].uv 
        co = mesh.vertices[index].co
        if (len(verts[index]) == 0):

            verts[index].append(round(uv.x,2))
            verts[index].append(round(uv.y,2))

            loc[index].append(round(co.x,2))
            loc[index].append(round(co.y,2))
            loc[index].append(round(co.z,2))

            count+=1
        else:
            uvs=verts[index]
            if(uv.x!=uvs[0] or uv.y!=uvs[1]):
                nIndex=len(verts.keys())

                while(len(verts[nIndex])>0):
                    nIndex+=1

                verts[nIndex].append(round(uv.x,2))
                verts[nIndex].append(round(uv.y,2))

                loc[nIndex].append(round(co.x,2))
                loc[nIndex].append(round(co.y,2))
                loc[nIndex].append(round(co.z,2))
                count+=1   

uvco=[]

for f, b in zip(verts.items(), loc.items()):
    uvs1 = f[1]
    locs1 = b[1]

    for j, k in zip(verts.items(), loc.items()):
        uvs2 = j[1]
        locs2 = k[1]

        if (uvs1[0] == uvs2[0] and uvs1[1] == uvs2[1] and locs1[0] == locs2[0] and locs1[1] == locs2[1] and locs1[2] == locs2[2]):
            uvco.append((uvs1[0],uvs1[1],locs1[0],locs1[1],locs1[2]))


duplicatesStripped = set(tuple(i) for i in uvco) 

print("Unique UV/Vertex coordinates: %s\n" %  duplicatesStripped)   

print("There are %d UV vertices" % len(duplicatesStripped))
```

It's <s>a little bit</s> very messy, but I have to go to lunch now, I'll continue testing it when I get back

Answer (score 0):

This will print the UV vertex count of active UV layer of active object in Object Mode (does not work in edit mode):

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

# Store all UV vertex locations
uv_coords = []
for loop in obj.data.loops:
    uv_loc = obj.data.uv_layers.active.data[loop.index].uv
    uv_coords.append(tuple(map(lambda x: round(x,3), uv_loc[:])))

# Keep only the unique ones and count them
print("object {0} has {1} UV vertices".format(obj.name, len(set(uv_coords))))
```

Comment: @ Jerryno thank you. Sorry that i had not written my question clearly. Now i have added more details. I want to find count of "UV vertices"

Comment: I think the answer you want is a [(total object verts - total uv verts)](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/cd72406d06888361fdf4)